# get_template_part inside get_template_part?

Tags: get-template-part

Ever tried this?

```
// template file
do_action( 'my_hook' );

// ex. functions.php
function my_hooked_template_part() {
  get_template_part( 'my_loop_part_file', 'default' );
}
add_action( 'my_hook', 'my_hooked_template_part' );

// my_loop_part_file-default.php
get_template_part( 'query', 'default' );
if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
etc.

// query-default.php
get_posts( array( 'whatever' => 'and_so_on', ) );
```

Maybe it's my setup, but it won't load the file. Could it be that it's too late for loading some other file inside? Can anyone confirm or this just a drawback of using the get_template_part() function (only one file - no nesting)?

Comment: I have recreated your example and files load fine. Check your actual code for typos or post it here so we can see it in details.

Comment: Does it really not load the file, or does it just not show anything? If you add `var_dump(__FILE__)` to each file, can you see that output?

Comment: Fun as it is: I pushed it on the staging server and everything works out fine. I guess it's in connection with the `wp_cron_bla` notice I get from time to time in my local setup. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your comments in the code above reflect the file names then it's a dash vs. underscore mistake.
Name of the second included file should be query-default.php

Comment: No, it's not. It's just a simplified example. But thanks for the look up! Already changed.

Comment: marked this as solution even if not :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [get_template_part codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part#Using_loop.php_in_child_themes):

> `<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>`
>
> will do a PHP require() for the first file that exists...

So it should just  be a standard `require` that you can put anywhere.